# How NOT to split after a combination of letters and numbers

Tags: java, regex, split

For a project I need to split the following string

```
210,'T99, Woody & Paul',1,'Geen omschrijving',5,3,7,'2008-04-12 21:00:00',16
```

Into this

```
210
'T99, Woody & Paul'
1
'Geen omschrijving'
5
3
7
'2008-04-12 21:00:00'
16
```

With this expression I've been able to split after the ',

```
(?<=')
```

I've tried a lot of things, but I haven't been able to split the integers without screwing up the 'T99, Woody & Paul' part.

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: It's probably possible, but if this is your own format, why are you putting yourself through this kind of regex based hell?

Comment: Why don't you just tokenize that string?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't my own format, so I'm forced to use regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your commas within the single quotes are always followed by space and your commas outside single quotes are not, then you can simply use this:

```
String test = "210,'T99, Woody & Paul',1,'Geen omschrijving',5,3,7,'2008-04-12 21:00:00',16";
String[] splitted0 = test.split(",(?!\\s)");
for (String split: splitted0) {
    System.out.println(split);
}
```

Output:

```
210
'T99, Woody & Paul'
1
'Geen omschrijving'
5
3
7
'2008-04-12 21:00:00'
16
```

Alternate solution with an actual `Pattern`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=,|^)('?).+?\\1(?=,|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
210
'T99, Woody & Paul'
1
'Geen omschrijving'
5
3
7
'2008-04-12 21:00:00'
16
```

The second solution doesn't "care" about spaces, however they will be added to the output (you can always `String.trim`).

Explanation for the non-trivial "alternate" solution:

```
(?<=,|^)
```

--> anything preceded by start of input or comma

```
('?)
```

--> optionally starts with `'`

```
.+?
```

--> any character, up to...

```
\\1
```

--> reference to group 1: `'` or nothing

```
(?=,|$)
```

--> followed by `,` or end of input

Comment: @Vertering you're welcome. Check my alternate solution as well just in case.

Comment: The alternate solution does work for this string, but not for all the strings. I have an SQLdump which I need to read and write to their respective objects, so it contains a lot of this kind of strings. While your alternate solution works perfectly for about the first 200, the last 200 came out like this:


2397
'Matt Andersen'
3
'',6,6,10,'2013-11-15 21:00:00'

Comment: @Vertering I guess there's a missing separator somewhere, or maybe some new line. The latter is easy to check: just add the flag `Pattern.MULTILINE` to `Pattern`'s initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format remains as simple as you've described, the following will work:

```
(?<=^|,)('[^']*'|[^,]*)
```

which you can see at http://rubular.com/r/wuPzWXOK0w

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex pattern I recently used in a project to split entries in a CSV file, where cells containing commas are protected with double quotes:

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Swap double quotes for single quotes, and you'll get the same functionality on a different character. [Working example in Java](http://ideone.com/4abftB).

This pattern doesn't work for extra quotes inside a cell. Whether the pattern works on cells containing newlines depends on whether multiline search is enabled or not.